# Escape a dollar sign in Selenium xpath locator

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I want to locate an element with attribute $9a but apparently the dollar sign is causing problems. When I use expression:

```
//td[@id='isc_6T']//span[@$9a='browse']
```

I get the following exception

```
The given selector //td[@id='isc_6T']//span[@$9a='browse'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //td[@id='isc_6T']//span[@$9a='browse'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'daniel', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Session ID: 7fdd584b-10b8-4c5a-ab64-72fe7cff7e2a
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=33.0}]
```

EDIT:
This is the HTML part that I am trying to locate. (id is dynamic so it can't be used directly)

```
<span handlenativeevents="false" $9a="browse" id="isc_T9" role="button">
<img border="0" align="TEXTTOP" height="18" width="18" draggable="true" suppress="TRUE" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;" id="isc_TA" src="some_image.png">
</span>
```

I have already created a workaround with parsing HTML with Jsoup to determine current dynamic id but I still want a cleaner solution

Comment: Is there any way to rewrite xpath query? Perhaps you could avoid `$`

Comment: can you show the html part of it?

Comment: I've already created a workaround but I still want to use this attribute somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '$' sign cannot appear in an XML attribute name, and the XPath syntax for names reflects the XML syntax.

According to this answer:

[What characters are allowed in an HTML attribute name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925994/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-html-attribute-name)

Dollar signs and many other things are allowed in HTML5 attribute names. However, unless someone has defined a mapping from such names to valid XML names, they can't be referenced from XPath; and I'm not aware of any such mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use XPath and want to use css it's fairly easy. Just a simple `\` will handle the `$`

```
[\$9a='browse']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might work:

```xml
//td[@id='isc_6T']//span[attribute::*[name() = '$9a' and . = 'browse']]
```

Michael Kay already mentioned that this is not allowed in XML, so this might not work with all XPath engines. However at least with IntelliJ's "search by xpath" it works.