# Is it safe to send input type checkbox using double bracket [] in the name attribute?

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

Some of tutorial show me to use checkbox with double bracket so the value can retrieved as array, but some of tutorial is not.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='hobby[]' value='reading'> Reading
```

Which one standart? And is it actually safe to send input type checkbox using double bracket []  in the name attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What characters are allowed in an HTML attribute name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925994/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-html-attribute-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only purpose of this approach is to use multi-dimentional `$_GET` array in PHP (and probably some other server-side languages).

**Approach №1: No brackets**

The way how we use it most of the time. Provided so you can see the difference between this approach and two others.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby_reading" value="1" /> Reading
</label>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby_programming" value="1" /> Programming
</label>
```

`var_dump($_GET)` output:

```
array(2) {
    ["hobby_reading"] => string(1) "1"
    ["hobby_programming"] => string(1) "1"
}
```

**Approach №2: Names in brackets**

Provides us a nested associative `hobby` array as a member of `$_GET` array.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[reading]" value="1" /> Reading
</label>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[programming]" value="1" /> Programming
</label>
```

`var_dump($_GET)` output:

```
array(1) {
    ["hobby"] => array(2) {
        ["reading"] => string(1) "1"
        ["programming"] => string(1) "1"
    }
}
```

**Approach №3: Double brackets**

Provides us a nested non-associative `hobby` array as a member of `$_GET` array.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="reading" /> Reading
</label>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="programming" /> Programming
</label>
```

`var_dump($_GET)` output:

```
array(1) {
    ["hobby"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(7) "reading"
        [1] => string(11) "programming"
    }
}
```

**Answering your question**

Yes. It is safe to use this approach, but you can  face some problems when trying to get inputs DOM elements by name with vanilla JavaScript or jQuery (here is how to solve the problem for jQuery: [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute))