# What characters are allowed (not allowed) in the names of custom data-* attributes?

Tags: html, xhtml, web-standards

I am developing a JS plugin for serving of retina images. The attributes that identify these images are supposed to be the following:

`data-retina@2x`, 
`data-retina@1.5x`, 
`data-retina@2.5x`.

Could you tell me if these attributes are valid? What characters are allowed (not allowed) in the names of custom data-* attributes in HTML and XHTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [definition of the `data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) in the W3C HTML5 Recommendation:

- In HTML5, the name must be *XML-compatible* (and it gets ASCII-lowercased automatically).
- In XHTML5, the name must be *XML-compatible* and must not contain uppercase ASCII letters.

The [definition of *XML-compatible*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible) says that it

- must not contain `:` characters
- must match the *`Name` production* in the XML 1.0 specification

This [*`Name` production*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) lists which characters are allowed.

---

**tl;dr**: For the part after `data-`, you may use the following characters:

- `0`-`9`
- `a`-`z`
- `A`-`Z` (not in XHTML5)
- `-` `_` `.` `·`
- and characters from these Unicode ranges:

  - [#x0300-#x036F] ([Combining Diacritical Marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks))
  - [#x203F-#x2040] (`‿` `⁀`)
  - [#xC0-#xD6]
  - [#xD8-#xF6]
  - [#xF8-#x2FF]
  - [#x370-#x37D]
  - [#x37F-#x1FFF]
  - [#x200C-#x200D] (ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER, ZERO WIDTH JOINER)
  - [#x2070-#x218F]
  - [#x2C00-#x2FEF]
  - [#x3001-#xD7FF]
  - [#xF900-#xFDCF]
  - [#xFDF0-#xFFFD]
  - [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

So the `@` (U+0040) is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer the [Before attribute name state](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#before-attribute-name-state) section of the HTML5 Spec:

> - **U+0009** CHARACTER TABULATION (tab)
> - **U+000A** LINE FEED (LF)
> - **U+000C** FORM FEED (FF)
> - **U+0020** SPACE
> - **Ignore** the character.
> - **U+002F** SOLIDUS (/)
>     Switch to the self-closing start tag state.
> - **U+003E** GREATER-THAN SIGN (>)
>     Switch to the data state. Emit the current tag token.
>     Uppercase ASCII letter
> - **Start** a new attribute in the current tag token. Set that attribute's name to the lowercase version of the current input character (add 0x0020 to the character's code point), and its value to the empty string. Switch to the attribute name state.
> - **U+0000** NULL
> - **Parse** error. Start a new attribute in the current tag token. Set that attribute's name to a U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER character, and its value to the empty string. Switch to the attribute name state.
> - **U+0022** QUOTATION MARK (")
> - **U+0027** APOSTROPHE (')
> - **U+003C** LESS-THAN SIGN (<)
> - **U+003D** EQUALS SIGN (=)
> - **Parse** error. Treat it as per the "anything else" entry below.
> - **EOF**
>     Parse error. Switch to the data state. Reconsume the EOF character.
> - **Anything else**
>     Start a new attribute in the current tag token. Set that attribute's name to the current input character, and its value to the empty string. Switch to the attribute name state.

In simple words:

> It says all characters except tab, line feed, form feed, space, solidus, greater than sign, quotation mark, apostrophe and equals sign will be treated as part of the attribute name. Personally, I wouldn't attempt pushing the edge cases of this though.

Inspired from: [What characters are allowed in an HTML attribute name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925994/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-html-attribute-name)