# How to get the uncompiled raw HTML content of a component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I would like to write a component in Angular 2 that displays and highlights HTML code. It should be possible to write the HTML code without needing to escape tags with `&lt;` and such.

In the end I would like to write something like this:

```html
<my-code-component>
    <span (click)="test()">My test code</span>
</my-code-component>
```

It should be displayed in the browser like this:

```html
<span (click)="test()">My test code</span>
```

So the raw HTML code should be shown as is.

---

In Angular 1, the way to do it would be to register a pre-[compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-) function in a directive, so that it can retrieve the content of the element before it has been compiled by angular. In Angular 2, all I can find is [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html), which is only executed after the code is already compiled, so the `(click)` attribute is missing from `innerHTML`.

Is there any such thing as a pre-compile function in Angular 2?

---

Another thing that I have discovered is the [`ngNonBindable`](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/ignoring-angular-2.0-bindings) attribute. It is supposed to prevent Angular 2 from compiling the element. However, even testing it like this:

```html
<div ngNonBindable>
    <span (click)="test()">My test code</span>
</div>
```

does not work. Instead, it throws lots of `InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '(click)' is not a valid attribute name.` errors, which seems to be related to [this bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27228) in the DOM specification.

Is this a bug in Angular 2, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [ngNonBindable](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/test/common/directives/non_bindable_spec.ts) seems to work only with interpolation. It looks like it's trying to compile something that it shouldn't, I mean, if you put that inside ngNonBindable angular2 shouldn't care about it and shouldn't throw. So I can't say for sure, maybe you could ask for it as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

In fact `(click)` is not a valid attribute name, at least in Chrome you can't add an attribute named `(click)`. Therefore this only works when Angular preprocesses the HTML and resolves the bindings before it adds the template to the DOM.

Comment: `(click)` is a valid attribute name [by the HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925994/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-html-attribute-name)), it is just not a valid argument to `setAttribute()` (whose [standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-setattribute) refers to [the XML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name)).

Comment: That's what I remembered, but I wasn't able to add it in Chrome devtools. Chrome just removed it.