# What does the search_/> do in this HTML code?

Tags: html, forms, search, web, input

This is a part of the code I found for a new tab page for firefox.

```
<input class="searchBar search_google"
       type="text" name="q" 
       placeholder="Google" search_/>
```

I don't understand the last part `search_/>` of the code.
Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Is it from inspector of your browser or you got it from page source?

Comment: It's just an HTML attribute. What it means in terms of the appearance or behaviour of the element will depend on the active CSS and JS.

Comment: It is from the page source. What kind of attribute is it, and what does it do?

Comment: straight out of the box, nothing

Comment: The list of attributes for the `<input>` tag in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) does not state the attribute called `search_`.

Comment: exactly, so someone's adding that attribute to use for themselves for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `search_/>` is equivalent to `search_="" />` where
the `/>` is simply closing the input element
and the `search_=""` is declaring an attribute 
`search_` that has no value set.

I assume that the coder originally had a `search` attribute to request that
the server carry out a search operation (of some kind or other) 
then later on they added an underscore to "comment it out"
thus leaving a visible reminder `search_` ready if they want to reverse their decision.

Comment: Can I declare any new attribute with any name in HTML?

Comment: There are some rules see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925994/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-html-attribute-name