# Why does .attributes contain invalid attribute names?

Tags: javascript, attributes

Here is a test case:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" x="="y">Test</div>
```

JS:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');

var attributes = [];

for (var i=0, len=div1.attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
  attributes[div1.attributes[i].nodeName] = div1.attributes[i].value;
}

console.log(attributes);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyGdxd

I know that the attributes are already invalid in the HTML but why do browsers still suggest an invalid `nodeName`.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's invalid HTML, any attribute added to an element will be available in javascript, and javascript doesn't really validate HTML on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is a bit ambiguous

> I know that the attributes are already invalid in the HTML but why do *browsers still suggest an invalid nodeName*

I'll try to give a few pointers that might be helpful.

In your example you have defined a number of [content attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Content_versus_IDL_attributes).  Running the code the **values** array contains the following values:

```
[id: "div1", x: "=", y": ""]
```

Now, according to the **.attributes()** [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)

> The Element.attributes property returns a live collection of all attribute nodes registered to the specified node. It is a NamedNodeMap, not an Array, so it has no Array methods and the Attr nodes' indexes may differ among browsers. To be more specific, attributes is a key/value pair of strings that represents any information regarding that attribute.

The **.attributes()** spec doesn't mention anything about validating content attributes explicitly set in the HTML code. As stated, it's just a live collection of all attributes parsed.

At the same time, if you try to use the **.getAttribute()** method for the invalid **y"** attribute, the code would still not complain and return an empty value.  But what happens when you try to set the value programmatically through **.setAttribute('y"', "123")**?

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'y"' is not a valid attribute name.
```

This proves exactly what @adeneo mentioned in his comment that Javascript doesn't validate HTML entities on the fly, but only through certain methods.

Another related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926136/2459094).  Also you can have a look at the [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926136/2459094) when it comes to allowed chars in attribute names.

Answer (score -2):

I changed your html code a little.

```
<div id="div1" x="y">Test</div>
```

And this is the javascript. It's working on codepen.

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');

var attributes = [];
var values = [];

for (var i=0, len=div1.attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
  attributes[i] = div1.attributes[i].nodeName;
  values[i] = div1.attributes[i].nodeValue;
}

console.log(attributes);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: This doesn't make any attempt to answer the question. *"...I know that the attributes are already invalid in the HTML but why do browsers still suggest an invalid `nodeName`."*