# HTML tables attribute to save hidden data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any attribute available in **html table td**  where i can save my data and get it easily using jquery.
Like suppose i have

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From above snippet, I can get Cell value through using [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function of jquery but i want something like this

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td dataSaveHere>Cell A</td>
        <td dataSaveHere>Cell B</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

That i store some values in td so that later i can access it **easily**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `data-*` prefixed custom attribute to persist arbitrary data which can be fetched using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

It also has native support, You can also use [Element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

```js
console.log($('td').data('id'));
console.log(document.querySelector('td').dataset.id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="1">Cell A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can by using jQuery data.

```
<td data-name="dataSaveHere">Cell A</td>
```

and access it using jQuery.

```
$('td').data('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create any attribute in html element like

```
$("your element").attr("attrname","your value")
```

if you want to read value

```
$("your element").attr("attrname")
```

Comment: Creating random attributes is generally not recommended and it's better to use `data-*` attributes.  Various reasons, mostly that it's not "valid" html.  A limited search came up with this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/926040/2181514