# Special characters in HTML attributes

Tags: html, rfc

When people ask about HTML attributes, they mostly mean the **value** of an HTML attribute. I am actually asking about real attributes.

Is the following valid?

```
<a href="test.html" data-attribute-with-&amp;-character="hello">world</a>
```

Until which degree are attribute names valid (multibyte for example)?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the HTML standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2

They must

> consist of one or more characters other than controls, U+0020 SPACE,
>   U+0022 ("), U+0027 ('), U+003E (>), U+002F (/), U+003D (=), and
>   noncharacters

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926136).